# Accurately placing text in activity

Tags: android, textview

As part of the android app I've been asked to write, there is a 'contact us' activity.  This activity is supposed to have the company logo at the top, then various contact points (accounts payable, HR, etc) on the left (one on each 'line') with the corresponding number aligned on the right.

I've spent quite a few hours on attempting to use different layouts and placing them in the XML but it looks terrible.

What approach is best to solve this?  It needs to look reasonable on both phones and tablets.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Table Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html). From the way you're describing your problem, `Table Layout` seems to be an apt solution. You can even design your layout with [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) as the base. However, you might have to use attributes such as `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`, `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and others.

Comment: Just minutes after posting I realised that if I put a horizontal layout with the logo, then another horizontal layout and inside that two vertical layouts, the textviews could simply go in them.<br/> Now, it looks good on my Galaxy Nexus but awful on my Xoom.  :(   Ghost, I'd ++ your answer but I lack the rep.

Comment: Yes, but don't you think it's too much of work? :) You can nest a Table Layout inside a Relative layout. No circus here. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: Hmm, OK.  I'll look at the table layout.  (not played with those before)

Comment: OK, google showed me a pretty good example.  Once again though, it looks fine on the phone but terrible on the tablet.  Can I scale the text based on the resolution?

Comment: Yes you can. Actually, Android does it for you. To support different screens, see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). For further reference, you can also see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html), [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html).

Comment: Many thanks Ghost.  I've read at one of those links but have only just understood.

Comment: You're welcome pal. Hmmm. It does take time to understand. Take small steps at a time. It'll be much easier that way.